# Nexus 5 Android 5.1 Problems with mobile data

Tags: nexus-5, stock-android, 5.1-lollipop

2 days ago I updated my Nexus 5 from Android 5.0.1 to Android 5.1. After the update was finished, everything worked as expected, but mobile data didn't work. I have tried turning on and off airplane mode, restarting the phone in safe mode, extracting and inserting the SIM...

What can I do?

Comment: Check the APN (Access point names) settings. It might be empty or reset to a default value.

Comment: I checked the APN and it's correct